# SwiftUI recalculate function result and display in TextView every second

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Simplified example, I have a function that just takes a double as a parameter and increases that value by 1% and returns it. I have spent hours trying to get what I think is a pretty simple functionality but to no avail...

Now on my Content View I want to display the result of 100 being passed into that function AND refresh the calculation every second. e.g. pass in 100, after 1 second: return 101 to the TextView, after 2 seconds return: 102.01, 3 seconds: 103.03 ...

I substituted my inc_by_one function call with a simple counter I increment by one with a state variable and it works as expected, i.e. updating every second, I'm mystified by why the inc_by_one function would perform any differently? **Code below**

My function:

```
func inc_by_one(dollar_amt: Double) -> Double {
    //increases the value provided by 1%
    return dollar_amt * 1.01
}
```

My ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var theValue = 0.0  
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Text("\(theValue)")
                .onReceive(timer) { time in
                    theValue = inc_by_one(dollar_amt: 100)
                }
```

Comment: have you tried this: `theValue = inc_by_one(dollar_amt: theValue)` and starting with `@State private var theValue = 100.0`

Answer (score 0):

When you call `inc_by_one(dollar_amt: 100)` you are passing `100` every time. So each time you call the function it multiplies 100 by 1.01.

You need to pass the current value of `theValue` and you need to set `theValue` to 100.0 initially.  You can also use a `specifier` to limit your output to 2 decimal places

Also, a note on style `_` isn't very "Swifty" - Convention is to use camel case.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var theValue = 100.0  
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Text("\(theValue, specifier:"%.02f")")
                .onReceive(timer) { time in
                    theValue = incByOne(dollarAmt: 100)
                }
        }
    }

    func incByOne(dollarAmt: Double) -> Double {
        return dollarAmt * 1.01
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, using a starting `theValue = 100.0` and passing the
`theValue` to the function, to achieve what you describe,
`...after 1 second: return 101 to the TextView, after 2 seconds return: 102.01, 3 seconds: 103.03 ...`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var theValue = 100.0  // <-- here
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(theValue)")
                .onReceive(timer) { time in
                    theValue = inc_by_one(dollar_amt: theValue) // <-- here
                }
        }
    }
    
    func inc_by_one(dollar_amt: Double) -> Double {
        //increases the value provided by 1%
        return dollar_amt * 1.01
    }
}
```